# Загрузка файлов и запись на диск, пауза

Tags: php, сервер

На сервер загружается 200 фоток, но чтение/запись на диск = 1mb/сек которое ограничивается хостером. При загрузке такого количества фоток, сервер сбрасывает загрузку. Я подумал что проблема в огранечении записи, но возможно ли что это сбрасывание срабатывает через долгую работу скрипта, типа загрузка больше 30сек(стандартное время выполения скрипта). В php.ini директивы которые отвечают за лимиты на загрузку\количества файлов стоят выше 100мб. Суммарный вес 200 фоток не превышает 50мб. Я загружаю файлы через один цикл, я правильно делаю? Возможно нужно ставить какие-то паузы, или как-то порциями загружать. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: увеличте время выполнение для этого скрипта или грузите фотки по ssh, ftp или sftp

Comment: да вообщем то это не выход. Каждый раз выгружать такое количество фоток вручную не камильфо, +это галерея с thumb. На счет увеличивать время выполнения, возможно, но я не уверен что проблема в этом. Благодарю за совет

Comment: смотри логи сервера почему он падает?

Comment: если бы еще возможность такая была бы=)

Comment: Можешь отправлять изображения по очереди используя ajax.